# How to replace a value in a list of lists with another list?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to replace a value in a 2d list of lists with another sublist (creating a 3d list of lists). Below is essentially what I want to do except I know you can only use append to add values to a list, not another sublist.

```
def make_new_array(array):
    for r_index, row in enumerate(array):
        for c_index, number in enumerate(row):
                if number%10==0:
                    array[r_index][c_index].append([10,20,30])
                else:
                    array[r_index][c_index].append([40])
    return array
```

for example if

```
array=[[10],[15, 20]]
```

I'd want the result to look like

```
make_new_array(array)=[[[10,20,30]],[[40],[10,20,30]]]
```

Comment: @timgeb - Presumably a list of lists.

Comment: That's probably it, thanks @iCodez

Comment: Please provide sample before-and-after lists.

Comment: What's the difference between what you want and `array[r_index][c_index].append([10,20,30])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greg!
You've mixed up signs != and ==. Also, you haven't to append anything. Look, here's a working code that solves your problem:

```
array=[[10], [15, 20]]
for r_index, row in enumerate(array):
    for c_index, number in enumerate(row):
            if number % 10 == 0:
                array[r_index][c_index] = [10, 20, 30]
            else:
                array[r_index][c_index] = [40]
print(array) #array = [[[10,20,30]],[[40],[10,20,30]]]
```

Good luck!

Comment: Ah thank you, I figured it was easy I just couldn't figure it out. If you couldn't tell I'm new to python.

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace values in `a`, not append to them. Here's a concise version to do it:

```
for i,j,t in ((i,j,x%10) for i,sl in enumerate(a) for j,x in enumerate(sl)):
    a[i][j] = [40] if t else [10,20,30]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
array[r_index] = newList

array[r_index] = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]
```